# Javascript. Why is Google map not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm not sure if I'm doing something dumb, but my google map doesn't show in this test page. Can you see any errors?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gomap-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#map").goMap({
                latitude: 56.948813,
                longitude: 24.104004,
                zoom: 6
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #map {
            width:700px;
            height:400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map">map goes here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting `.js` at the end of your link to google maps.

Comment: So should be `src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false.js"`

Comment: what errors do you get in the console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f8kAT/ - works!

Comment: If you have an error `jQuery is not defined` then add `http:` in front of `//code.jquery.com.....`.

Comment: Your code works fine for me [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJPyt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what goMaps is, but using the google maps API directly is simple enough. The following should do what you want (without go map):

```
$(function() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.948813, 24.104004),
        zoom: 6
    };

    var newMap = new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0], mapOptions);
});
```

**JSFiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/4mRhB/3/

The full documentation for google maps can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). Best of luck!